# Software for parallel incomplete LU factorisation

Tags: sparse-matrix, software, matrix-factorization

I am looking for a software package to compute incomplete LU factorisations in parallel. Further considerations are:

- The package must allow for arbitrary level-of-fill or threshold-based truncation. ILU(0) is not good enough.
- The package must be "direct", i.e. based on the same recursion formulae as the exact factorisation and not on some iterative procedure. The [approach by Chow and Patel](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/140968896) is not suitable for our purposes.
- Both multi-threaded and distributed parallelism is acceptable.

As far as I can tell, no such package seems to exist, but maybe I missed something?

Comment: Right off top of my head, I do not know if the second bullet point is satisfied for [SuperLU](https://github.com/xiaoyeli/superlu), [SuperLU Doc](https://portal.nersc.gov/project/sparse/superlu/superlu_ug.pdf). This is quite a go-to package for iLU, so I wonder if you've taken a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. SuperLU seems to only provide a serial ILU code, however.

Answer (score 1):

I think [PARDISO](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-intel-mkl-pardiso-parallel-direct-sparse-solver-interface) from Intel MKL should have the implementation you are looking for.
According to the [Preconditioners section](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-preconditioners-based-on-incomplete-lu-factorization-technique), it allows for both ILU(0) and ILU(T). PARDISO natively offers shared-memory parallelization, and I do not believe any iterative procedure is used inside.

So, [`dscrilut`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-dcsrilut) seems to satisfy all your requirements, from the first glance.

I also recommended in the comments to look at [SuperLU](https://github.com/xiaoyeli/superlu); however, it seems that it might offer only a serial version.